# What is the difference between `#![feature(no_core)]` and `#![no_core]`?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between `#![feature(no_core)]` and `#![no_core]`?

Are both required to compile without libcore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `#![no_core]` you have to use a nightly compiler and enable that via `#![feature(no_core)]`. So yes, they are both required if you want to omit libcore.

So-called "feature gates" are used to enable unstable behavior of the Rust language, so you are required to explicitly opt-in and acknowledge that it can change in the future.

There is always a tracking issue for a feature where you can lookup the status of a feature. In the case for `no_core` it is [#29539](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29639). You can also get the tracking number from the source code, e.g. when looking at [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/core/future/future.rs.html#11).